# How to select only the front bunch of objects?

Tags: selection-tools

Let's take this for example:

[image]

Here each cube is a separate object. And i need to select only the front cubes, like this:
[image]

But i don't want to select it one by one. I've tried to select it in orthographic mode by using Select Box

[image]

And it selected all of them.
So how can i select only front objects?

I'm using Blender 2.82